# How to detect Internet Connection Sharing through sniffing?

Tags: tcp, internet-connection

I'm sniffing my current connection, but I have a second computer linked to mine with [ICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing). And my application makes no difference between the two. How can I detect the second one and filter it?

Comment: Suggest move to ServerFault; question is not programming-related

Answer (score 1):

You could filter by source/destination IP if either one is your PC's IP.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is ignoring the packets that are from Mac to Mac from the same machine, that means they are looping to the second one.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: is this an answer or a follow-up to ThiefMaster's answer?